# Automatically Print CF/PDF after Modal is accepted

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a print label button that opens a modal and asks what number to begin with to print the labels. Upon accept I want it to take the input number as a variable then start printing the labels without showing the customers any screen by just automatically printing from the pdf and showing them the same screen as the print label button. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/1zka4soy/4/

**html**

```
     <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#LabelMaker">PRINT LABELS</button>
                            </div>

<!-- Label Maker Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="LabelMaker" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Label Maker</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <label for="LabelNum">Please enter label start number:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LabelNum" id="LabelNum">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary label_accept">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Label Maker Modal -->
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // What happens when a user hits the "Accept" button on the dealer form
    $(".label_accept").click(function(){
        $('#LabelMaker').modal('hide');

    });

});
```

**coldfusionpdf**

```
<cfset tempFilePath = "/mytemppath.pdf">
<cfpdfform source="forms/DealerLabel.pdf" action="populate" destination="#tempFilePath#">

    <cfpdfformparam name="One" value="<!---VariableSomeHow--->">
</cfpdfform>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=LabelMaker.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#tempFilePath#" deleteFile="true">
```

Comment: Print it where?  Do you have printer set up on your network for which you can use cfprint?

Comment: well many people will be using the application so it would automatically print to there default printer

Comment: My co-workers did something like that several years ago.  We used ColdFusion to produce the document to be printed, and classic ASP to print to the user's default printer.  Good luck.